# Passing void method with parameters to another method with std::function and std::bind C++

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class A
{
public:
    A() {}

    void print(std::function<void(int)> func);

    virtual ~A() {}
};

void A::print(std::function<void(int)> func)
{
    func();
}

void printInt(int a)
{
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    A a;

    a.print(std::bind(&printInt, 3));

    return 0;
}
```

Let's say I have this sample of code. How to pass void method printInt(int a) to A::print(std::function func) and call there function that has been passed? I get "candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided" and I don't know how to deal with that.

Edit:
I should have mentioned it but my goal is to pass that integer but actually I have no idea how. When I try something like this:

```
void A::print(std::function<void(int a)> func)
{
 func(a);
}
```

I get "error: ‘a’ was not declared in this scope".

Comment: You're calling a function that takes an `int` with no arguments (`func()`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't intend to pass any arguments to `func`, it should be `std::function<void(void)>`. A signature of `void(int)` means you intent to feed it an integer, something it will *expect*. And your code clearly doesn't provide the required argument.

---

If you do intent to pass an argument to `func`, it needs to be a parameter of `A::print`, like so:

```
void A::print(std::function<void(int)> func, int a) {
  func(a);
}
```

Your attempt specified the functions parameter is named `a` which is moot. Since there is no `a` in `A::print` to refer to. The above also means you can dispense with `bind`:

```
a.print(&printInt, 3);
```

Comment: Then you won't use std::bind(), you'll use std::ptr_fun instead.

Comment: @StoryTeller My bad sir

Comment: @SoronelHaetir - No, you won't use `std::ptr_fun`, and please don't suggest  it. It's deprecated in C++11, and gone forever in C++17.

Comment: With C++11, I'd avoid `std::bind` and use a lambda instead.  To me, lambda expressions are much easier to read.  2¢

Comment: @Eljay - I concur. But in C++11 specifically, if you need to move something into the closure, `std::bind` is unavoidable. In C++14, lambdas all the way.

Comment: @StoryTeller I edited my post, I want to pass that argument, but I don't know how to provide it. Any idea how?

Answer (score 0):

Your bind() creates a function that takes no arguments but A::print expects a function that takes 1. It then tries calling that function as if it takes no arguments.

The answer is to change A::print to take a std::function that takes no arguments.