# Unable to compile using std::function to pass a void function as a parameter

Tags: visual-c++, std-function

I have followed the ideas I saw on the internet:

```
UpdateColumnIndexVector(m_vColumnIndexesToExclude, WriteColumnIndexesToExclude);
```

That calls:

```
void CCreateReportDlg::UpdateColumnIndexVector(ColumnIndexVector &rvData, std::function<void()> WriteToRegistry)
{
    bool bModified = true;
    // Code simplified

    if (bModified)
    {
        WriteToRegistry();
    }
}
```

The function being passed in:

```
void CCreateReportDlg::WriteColumnIndexesToExclude()
{
    ByteVector vData(m_vColumnIndexesToExclude.begin(), m_vColumnIndexesToExclude.end()); // int to BYTE

    const CString strSection = theApp.GetActiveScheduleSection(_T("Options"));

    theApp.WriteProfileVector(strSection, _T("AssignStatesEx"), vData);
}
```

When I compile:

> error C3867: `CCreateReportDlg::WriteColumnIndexesToExclude`: non-standard syntax; use `&` to create a pointer to member

Yet, if I change this line to:

> ```
> UpdateColumnIndexVector(m_vColumnIndexesToExclude, &WriteColumnIndexesToExclude);
> ```

That does not compile either:

> error C2276: `&`: illegal operation on bound member function expression
>
> error C2660: `CCreateReportDlg::UpdateColumnIndexVector`: function does not take 1 arguments

`WriteColumnIndexesToExclude` is a `private` member of the dialog class.

What am I doing wrong?

PS. My project is MFC C++ Dialog.

Comment: I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/47732679/2287576 and it still does not work.

Comment: It is a non-static function that requires a `this` argument, use `std::bind`, `std::memfn`, or lambda syntax.

Comment: BTW there is no such thing as a "void function".  `void` is not a function type.  You probably meant "void-returning function", but the return type isn't important here, the fact it's a non-static member function is.

Comment: @BenVoigt I see. I don’t want a lambda really I don’t think. See if I can get to grips with the others you mention. What is the simplest?

Comment: `std::bind(&CCreateReportDlg::WriteColumnIndexesToExclude, this)`

Comment: @BenVoigt Is that code passed as the parameter to my one? The one with std::function?

Comment: Yes, that's the value to pass in the `std::function<void ()>` argument, where you thought it should be `&WriteColumnIndexesToExclude`

Comment: If you ever do consider lambdas, that version is pretty simple and even a bit shorter as it doesn't require the class name: `[this]() { WriteColumnIndexesToExclude(); }`

Comment: @BenVoigt Hhm. Awesome. Will try later!

Comment: @BenVoigt It is now working fine with the lambda expression. I appreciate your help getting it working. If you wants to put an answer together I will upvote and accept it.